# CMake error when generating VS project using VTK

Tags: vtk

I made a very simple CMakeLists file similar as the one shown [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Build_System_Migration):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (MyProject)

find_package (VTK REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
include (${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_library (MyLib STATIC source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyLib ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

After configuring in CMake I set the VTK_DIR variable to the directory containing the VTKConfig file.
After generating in CMake I get 3 errors:

```
Target "MyLib " links to target "Qt5::XXX" but the target
was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

where XXX is either Help, Network or UiTools.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a vtk problem but rather a qt problem. Most likely, the vtk libraries you are using are dependant on some Qt modules which you need to install separately (they do not come with vtk). If you have them already, just put

```
find_package(Qt5 Help Network UiTools REQUIRED)
```

before the find_package(vtk) line, cmake should find it.

Alternatively, if you compiled VTK yourself and you are sure you don't need qt for anything, disable all qt-dependant parts of it in cmake (just search for "qt" in cmake and disable everything you don't need) and compile it again.